# Matlab variables empty after parfor loop

Tags: ubuntu, matlab, parfor

I am trying to run some of my Matlab code in parallel on a Ubuntu 13.04 machine with Matlab 2013a and an i7 processor:

```
range = [0.75 0.8];
scores = cell(length(range), 1);

parfor i=1:length(range)
   pca_accuracy = range(i);
   scores{i, :} = cross_validation(data_features, labels, 69, pca_accuracy);
end
```

`cross_validation()` returns a matrix. However, after this code is run, variable `scores` is still a 2-by-1 cell array with each cell being empty. It seems as if `cross_validation()` does not return anything.

If I convert the parfor-loop into a normal for-loop, it also works fine on this computer. I also tested this code (with the parfor-loop) on another computer (Windows 7, Matlab 2013b) and it works fine on there.

A short version of `cross_validation()` is:

```
function scores = cross_validation(data_features, labels, number_of_test_blocks, pca_accuracy)
   number_of_samples = size(data_features, 1);
   samples_per_test_block = ceil(number_of_samples/number_of_test_blocks);
   scores = zeros(number_of_test_blocks, samples_per_test_block);
end
```

Could anyone give advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a slimmed down variant of cross_validation and the variables so we can check if we have the same behavior on our machines?

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks! I added the code to the initial post.

Comment: Perhaps `parfor` in 2013a gets thrown off by `scores{i, :}`. Have you tried assigning to `scores{i, 1}` instead?

Comment: @s.bandara Thanks for your answer. This doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think this will leave your variables empty, but assigning to `pca_accuracy ` may prevent parallelization (assigning to the same thing with all workers). -- Could you give an example of all variables? As is your code is not runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my initial problem:

I was running the above Matlab script from the terminal using the command `matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "run('scriptname')"`. For some reason this did not assign the values to `scores` after the parfor-loop.

Now, running the script either with `matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "scriptname"` or executing the script from within Matlab makes it work perfectly.

@mathworks: is this a bug? :)